# How to find equal text in div with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have html:

```
<div class="items-list-container">
   <div class="fieldset-item">Something</div>
   <div class="fieldset-item">Something 2</div>
   <div class="fieldset-item">Something 3</div>
   <div class="fieldset-item">Something 4</div>
   <div class="fieldset-item">Something 5</div>
</div>
```

I need to find out with jQuery if variable `t` is equal with text in `fieldset-item` and if it is - set `fieldet-item` class css to: `display: block`. For example if

```
t = "Something 2"
```

html should look like:

```
   <div style="display: block;" class="items-list-container">
       <div class="fieldset-item">Something</div>
       <div style="display: block;" class="fieldset-item">Something 2</div>
       <div class="fieldset-item">Something 3</div>
       <div class="fieldset-item">Something 4</div>
    </div>
```

I can find all text in div with:

```
var text = $(".items-list-container").text();
```

How should I add css to specific matching div?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$('.items-list-container .fieldset-item:contains("'+ t +'")').css('display', 'block');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7DTMf/2/)**

About above code see [@fudgey comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829330/how-to-find-equal-text-in-div-with-jquery/11829381#comment15727159_11829381).

**More accurately**

```
$('.items-list-container .fieldset-item').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim() == t;
}).css('display', 'block');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7DTMf/4/)**

**Related refs:**

- **[:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)**
- **[.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter)**

Comment: +1; but I wouldn't use `contains()` because searching for `Something 2` would match on `Something 22`

Comment: what version of jquery did you test this with ? i'm getting "TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'contains'" with 1.7.2

Comment: @helmus I've added the demo for each

Comment: +1 for demo, nice ( should have done that first thing tough ;) )

Answer (score 5):

I have a couple of extensions to the jQuery `:contains()` selector that might be useful ([original gist](https://gist.github.com/461488))

```
/* jQuery selector to match exact text inside an element
 *  http://wowmotty.blogspot.com/2010/05/jquery-selectors-adding-contains-exact.html
 *  :containsExact()     - case insensitive
 *  :containsExactCase() - case sensitive
 *  :containsRegex()     - set by user ( use: $(el).find(':containsRegex("/(red|blue|yellow)/gi")') )
 */
$.extend( $.expr[":"], {
    containsExact: $.expr.createPseudo ?
        $.expr.createPseudo(function(text) {
            return function(elem) {
                return $.trim(elem.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) === text.toLowerCase();
            };
        }) :
        // support: jQuery <1.8
        function(elem, i, match) {
            return $.trim(elem.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) === match[3].toLowerCase();
        },

    containsExactCase: $.expr.createPseudo ?
        $.expr.createPseudo(function(text) {
            return function(elem) {
                return $.trim(elem.innerHTML) === text;
            };
        }) :
        // support: jQuery <1.8
        function(elem, i, match) {
            return $.trim(elem.innerHTML) === match[3];
        },

    containsRegex: $.expr.createPseudo ?
        $.expr.createPseudo(function(text) {
            var reg = /^\/((?:\\\/|[^\/])+)\/([mig]{0,3})$/.exec(text);
            return function(elem) {
                return reg ? RegExp(reg[1], reg[2]).test($.trim(elem.innerHTML)) : false;
            };
        }) :
        // support: jQuery <1.8
        function(elem, i, match) {
            var reg = /^\/((?:\\\/|[^\/])+)\/([mig]{0,3})$/.exec(match[3]);
            return reg ? RegExp(reg[1], reg[2]).test($.trim(elem.innerHTML)) : false;
        }

});
```

So with the above code, you can just do this:

```
$('div:containsExact("Something 2")').show();
```

or for case sensitive searches use:

```
$('div:containsExactCase("Something 2")').show();
```

The last extension uses regex, which is useful but maybe not in your case :)

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

Loop though each `.fieldset-item` find the one where `.text()` matches the `t`. Add the css.

```
$('.fieldset-item').each(function(i, item){
    if ($(item).text() == t){
        $(item).css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

or like @helmus mentioned but then with the t variable:

```
$(".fieldset-item:contains('" + t + "')", ".items-list-container")
     .css('display', 'block');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(".fieldset-item:contains('Something 2')", ".items-list-container").css('display', 'block');
```